# Inner workings of GPS Spoofing Apps?

Tags: ios, geolocation, gps

I'm wondering how apps like [Ultfone](https://www.ultfone.com/ios-location-changer.html) spoof locations.

What kind of API does it use on the iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They work by utilising the developer tools services available over USB on trusted connections to iOS devices. In there, Apple provides a service for simulating location.

This is the same method used when a developer uses Apple's Xcode to simulate a location on a connected device in order to test their app in development.